# Headless build should include all dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I have a product consisting of several plugins that I want to build. The endresult I want is a zipfile containing all my jar files AND the dependencies I have, i.e `org.eclipse.swt.X.jar`, `org.eclipse.ui.Y.jar` etc.

It's building and zipping ok but I only get my plugins, not the dependencies. I'm guessing there is a parameter or XML attribute that sets this, if so what and where?

At the moment I have only modified build.xml, build.properties and allElements.xml. The rest of the build files (if they are used) are the Eclipse 3.4.1 templates.

The build is being update from Eclipse 3.3 to 3.4.1, so I'm guessing that could be the root of the issue.

Comment: Is your product based on features or plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem and finds this question, for me the problem was solved by setting the parameters:

```
  <param name="topLevelElementType" value="product"/>    
  <param name="topLevelElementId" value="(productid)"/>
```

for all targets to build. This can be set either in the build.properties or in the build.xml file